# Viewing non-feature index in R/ R studio

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, similarity, hierarchical-clustering

I'm trying to cluster items (find similar items) based on their attributes. I initially had a CSV of the format:

Item | Attribute1 | Attribute2.....about 200 attributes

Since its a mixed format set of attributes (INT, String...), I decided to concatenate the attributes and now I have:

Item | ConcatenatedAttributes.

My clustering code is:

```
 uniqueItem <- unique(as.character(data$ConcatenatedAttributes))
    distanceMatrix <- stringdistmatrix(uniqueItem ,uniqueItem ,method = "jw")
    rownames(distanceMatrix ) <- uniqueItem 
    hc <- hclust(as.dist(distanceMatrix ))
    dfClust <- data.frame(uniqueItem , cutree(hc, k=200))
```

Now, I want to be able to see which Items have been clustered together based on their similarities of the ConcatenatedAttributes field. How can I do that?

So, something like:

ClusterNumber | Item |

Comment: Why do you think concatenating everything into one unmanageable field and then abusing a string distance is a good idea?!?

Answer (score 0):

You want to `group_by` your data frame.

One obvious way is to use a `for` loop. Most R fans will suggest to learn `dplyr`.

But IMHO, you idea of concatenating everything into one unmanageable field and then abusing a string distance is just *horrible*.